# how and where to write this code in web.conf in my polling application

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

How and where to write this code in `web.conf` in my polling application, which is console based?

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Comment: you can't write this in a web.config !

Comment: same thing, failed. It's code, so place it in your code not the config.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you by `web.conf` refers to the `Web.config` file of your application, which is an XML-based description of your applications configuration. It would not be the place to write the information, since you `Sleep` statement is `C#` and should be written in a file ending in  `.cs`.

You say polling, so you probably want some kind of repeated action to happen with certain intervals. You could do this using a while loop

```
while(true) // replace with condition enabling you to stop the application.
{
    // Do your thing 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

But you could also choose to use some kind of [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where you use the Callback to do the scheduled interval.

Answer (score 0):

Describe you questions complete and clear.
By the way! U said it is a Console Application. So what is the Web.Conig (Web.Conig is the configuration file of Web Apps like ASP.NET. In Console and WinForm apps there's App.Config) !?
If you want to have delay in your app, so it doesn't need to do anything in Config file.
Use `Thread.Sleep(*TimeInMilliSec*);` in wherever of your code that you want to have delay.
*(If you're looking for sth else, tell in comment)*